# Advice for USB Sniffer

Tags: usb

I am looking for a USB protocol analyzer and was wondering if anyone had any experience with one.  So far, I am looking at an [Internal Test Instruments](http://www.internationaltestinstruments.com/storefront/Store_Prod1_1480A-USB-20-Protocol-Analyzer.aspx) and a [Beagle USB 12](http://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle_usb12/).  I only need to watch the full speed (12 Mbs).  I need some low-level protocol information so I'm looking at hardware solutions.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using the Beagle USB 12 over the last year or so and have not run into any problems.  It has been very useful in debugging some protocol problems I was having with an embedded USB chip.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered doing it in software? Run something on your PC to watch the USB traffic at that level, instead of trying to intercept the actual USB lines in hardware. There are several ways of doing this.

If you absolutely need hardware, consider the [ZeroPlus LogicCube](http://www.nkcelectronics.com/zeroplus-lap16032u-logic-ana16032.html), it's cheaper, and supports decoding USB 1.1. However the software might not be as nice as your link, since it's more general purpose, and not specifically for USB.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you were looking for hardware, but cost-wise it makes a lot of sense to look at software:

- Usblyzer is pretty sophisticated and has a nice interface- also a free demo
- usbsnoopypro is free and open source, though not quite as user friendly

If you REALLY have to have hardware, go with the big boys: [ellisys](http://www.ellisys.com/) ([reviews](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=533))

Answer (score 2):

VMWare can [dump all USB traffic](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html) to the VM to a giant text-file.

They also have a [nice GUI tool](http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/) for analysing the resulting USB log.

I like it because I can do everything on windows. It does not require a linux-host, like every other software-USB-sniffer I looked at.

If you are ok with linux, I believe [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can [capture usb](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB).